# How to detect when a game controller gets connected in Android

Tags: android, react-native, gamecontroller

I'm trying to make a native module for React Native/Expo using [Expo Modules API](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/overview/) to support game controllers in my app.

On iOS there is a notification/event that is posted immediately after a game controller gets connected to the device called [GCControllerDidConnect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1458856-gccontrollerdidconnect), and another similar notification/event called [GCControllerDidDisconnect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1458875-gccontrollerdiddisconnect) that is posted immediately after a game controller is disconnected.

I was not able to find an equivalent event on Android for this purpose.

Based on [Android's developer docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/game-controllers/controller-input#input), it is suggested to call [`getSources()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice#getSources()) to get a list of connected input devices and check for certain properties on the returned values to ensure a game controller with the buttons/controls that are needed in your app has been connected.

The problem with this approach is that I need to manually check the connected devices with an arbitrary interval to know when the game controller I need has been connected.

Is there something that I'm missing? Can you think of a way to circumvent this limitation?

All ideas are appreciated!